# Expiring a cookie when sending a redirect response not working

Tags: java, redirect, cookies

I'm trying to invalidate/expire an insecure cookie from a securely accessed servlet and send a redirect back to the client.  However, when the redirect is followed, the request still contains the original, unexpired, uninvalidated (is that a word) cookie.

Here's a more detailed description of the flow:
1) Client requests a particular insecure url backed by Servlet A. 
2) Servlet A detects that there is a Cookie XX and redirects to a secure url backed by  Servlet B 
3) Servlet B does its magic, then invalidates Cookie XX by setting the MaxAge to 0 and redirects to Servlet A via an insecure url. 
4) In Servlet A, I'm still able to access the cookie just as it was in the first request.

Can anyone lend a hand?  I was under the impression and can't find evidence to the contrary that when a cookie is sent back with a redirect response, it is still processed before the new request is sent out.  This is happening in all browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) that I have access to, so I don't think its a browser thing.  In HTTPFox and the Chrome Developer tools I can see the original cookie getting sent in the first and second request, the invalidated cookie coming back in the response to the second request, and the original cookie being sent again in the third request.  I've tried setting the MaxAge to 0, setting the value of the cookie to null/empty string, and another value but it never changes.  All of the server side code is done in Java if it matters.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an oversight on my part.  When Servlet B invalidated Cookie XX, it also set the cookie's path to something other than what it originally was.  That, in effect, created a Cookie XX-B and had no effect on the original Cookie XX.  Making sure my cookie's paths were the same fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making sure that the domain and paths for the invalidated cookie is the same as the original cookie?

Also, a better way to handle sensitive cookies is setting the 'secure' flag on the original cookie.  That will tell the browser to never send the cookie over an insecure connection.

Answer (score 0):

In two separate projects I've had to invalidate a cookie. This is what I have had to do:

1. Get the cookie in question from the HTTP request object
2. Set cookie max age to by invoking `Cookie.setMaxAge(int)`.
3. Call the `Cookie.setPath(String)` method, **even if path is to remain the same**
4. Add the cookie back into the HTTP response object, I.e. `HttpServletRespons.addCookie(cookie)`

Only after executing all the steps above did the browser stop passing the cookie back to server on subsequent requests.