# Can't remove JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: spring, browser, cookies

I am using a Spring controller with a HttpServletRequest and response to remove cookies.

When I need to remove the cookie, I have this code:

```
   Cookie[] allCookies = request.getCookies();

for (int i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i++)
{
   String name = allCookies[i].getName();
   if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("JSESSIONID"))
   {
    logger.info(i + " Name=" + name + " Value=" + allCookies[i].getValue());
    cookieToDelete = allCookies[i];
    cookieToDelete.setValue("");
    cookieToDelete.setMaxAge(0);
    cookieToDelete.setVersion(0);
    cookieToDelete.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookieToDelete);
   }
}
```

After this execution, all cookies with the name JSESSIONID should be removed.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the content type and domain as explained here [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet) .You cold also try expiring the session using SessionRegistry explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#list-authenticated-principals)