# Invalid a session when user makes logout (Spring)

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

Imagine the user A have multiple logins (are logged in) in diferent machines. When he logs out in one machine, the other sessions should automatically redirect to login page.

how i can implement this in spring security?
For now, i have tis http configuration on security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <anonymous />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.do" />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />

</http>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recomment you to have a look at SessionRegistry .You can check this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#list-authenticated-principals) . There has been a discussion on this at [Is it possible to invalidate a spring security session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478188/is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session/8487445#8487445) . Check this out too

Spring sessions are stored as JsessionID cookies. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508129/cant-remove-jsessionid-cookie/8509674#8509674) for a discussion on cookie removal.