# Update domain of existing cookie

Tags: java, cookies, dns

I have a site name www.goo.com and i used to save cookie without declaring domain name when creating the cookie.
Now, i want to add sub domain foo.goo.com
I save the cookie in the domain and not in the sub domain.
There are 2 problems:

1. I want to delete the old cookie.
   I tried to  do 'cookie.setMaxAge(0)' already and the problem is  that in Firefox and chrome it do not work. it work only in IE.
   why? and what i can do about it?
2. When i do

   ```
   Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
   if (cookie != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cookie .length; i++) {
          cookie[i].getDomain();   //here i get null.why?
      }
   }
   ```

Why i get null in the getDomain() line?

**Edit:**

i tried to add this line:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

to send the content type.

I also tried to send the cookie through the response.

Someone have another idea, for the 2 problems the presents here?

Comment: this cookie is set... so he have the domain.

Comment: Tried sending the cookie through the response? `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", name + "=" + value + "; Max-Age=" + maxAge + "; expires=" + expiresTime);`

Comment: its the same like to do addcookie right?
what is expires?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. About `max-age` and `expires`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age, just use one of them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Answered here: [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet) (you need to send a text/html content type)
2. When a client sends cookies to the server, it only sends the name/value. The other fields are only available when setting the cookie.

Comment: The second answer should be correct. As for the first, I have never used java servlets and I have no clue why Firefox and Chrome disobey the expire field. A possible issue (IIRC) is that all fields (path, domain, secure, etc) must match for the cookie to be erased rather than creating another cookie that is deleted immediately.