# Delete cookie from a servlet response

Tags: servlets, cookies, spring-mvc

I would like to know how to delete a cookie in an `HttpServletResponse` in Spring MVC. I have the login method where I create the cookie and the logout where I want to delete it, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Login(HttpServletResponse response, String user, String pass) {     
    if (user != null && pass != null && userMapper.Users.get(user).getPass().equals(pass)){
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("user", user);
        cookie.setPath("/MyApplication");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setMaxAge(3600);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("user", user);
        return new ModelAndView("home", "model", model);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {     

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        for(int i = 0; i< cookies.length ; ++i){
            if(cookies[i].getName().equals("user")){
                //Cookie cookie = new Cookie("user", cookies[i].getValue());
                //cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                //response.addCookie(cookie);
                cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
                break;
            }
        } 
        return new ModelAndView("login");
 }
```

I thought it was only needed to change the `maxAge`, but in the browser the cookie don't change. I even tried to rewrite a cookie with the same name in the commented block but it doesn't work either.

Comment: have u tried cookie.setvalue("")??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)

Comment: yes, the setValue("") did not work either...

Comment: The commented code with `new Cookie()` should work, in addition to set the same cookie domain.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Setting the maximum age to `0` is right. But it must have **exactly** the same other cookie properties, except of the value. Thus exactly the same domain, path, secure, etc. The value is optional, it can best be set to `null`.

So, given the way how you created the cookie,

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("user", user);
cookie.setPath("/MyApplication");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setMaxAge(3600);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

it needs to be removed as follows:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("user", null); // Not necessary, but saves bandwidth.
cookie.setPath("/MyApplication");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setMaxAge(0); // Don't set to -1 or it will become a session cookie!
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

That said, I'm not sure how it's useful to store the logged-in user as a cookie. You're basically also allowing the enduser to manipulate its value. Rather just store it as a session attribute instead and call `session.invalidate()` on logout.

Comment: Thanks, that's it, well I will work with this framework from now on, and I am just learning how it works, and I was trying to understand out to use cookies here, that's why I made the login via user.

Comment: "I'm not sure how it's useful to store the logged-in user as a cookie." Maybe relevant if you also are linked to a Single Sign On system and need to permanently 'logout' user via its deposited cookie.

Comment: Path value was it. I set cookie with "/mywebapp" path and later tried to delete it with "/" root path. It did not work but had to use exact values cookie.setPath("/mywebapp"), cookie.setMaxAge(0), cookie.setValue(null), response.addCookie(cookie)

Comment: Also works with session cookies? The ones that are initially stored without max age? Or is their expiration controlled by the **browser only**?

Answer (score -4):

No need to use your own code. Just configure rememberMeServices bean that would create cookie while user' logging in with rememberMe option checked, and would delete it after logout.