# How to change the session cookie in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, session-cookies

When the user does a logout (or login, for that matter) I'd like to ensure that the value of the users session cookie is changed. How can I do that? If I just do `session.invalidate()` tomcat does not return a session cookie header since there is no active session, and thus the cookie stays the same. If I do `session.invalidate(); request.getSession()` to create a new session, the new session gets the same sessionId, and thus cookie also stays the same.

(I'd like to change the session cookie value since we have several WAR that share one sessionId, and I cannot easily invalidate the sessions in the other WARs as well.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to delete the cookie manually by [adding an expired version of the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9821919/21499) to the response. That is, you find the cookie in `request.getCookies()`, set its maxAge to 0 and do `response.addCookie(..)` . You need also to invalidate the session and take care not to recreate a session on that request. This means you can't display a "you are now logged out" page directly but have to do a client-side redirect to such a page - which will now get assigned a new session cookie.