# Deleting a Cookie from Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have an application which have a login filter, in which I am creating the cookie like below.

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("testCookie","Value");
ck.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(ck);
```

And in the logout button I am removing the cookie like below.

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("testCookie",null);
ck.setPath("/");
ck.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(ck);
```

But when I try to login again the cookie is existing. I have followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821919/delete-cookie-from-a-servlet-response)

Please let me know how can i remove the cookie completely when i logout from the application.

[image]

Comment: Press F12 in browser and check Network tab. Check the HTTP `Set-Cookie` response header and `Cookie` request header. Verify if all is right over there.

Comment: In network tab, I am seeing only the call to my url and then the call to server. Nothing about cookie is shown there

Comment: This comment is a bit too ambiguous. First this: do you know how to interpret HTTP requests? Be honest if you actually can't.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the network tab in the developers tool

Comment: You thus can't. The screenshot namely doesn't show HTTP headers (and thus cookies). Click the name of each individual entry and explore the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/cookies.html
hope it helps. try

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("testCookie","");
```

instead of using null as value

Comment: Instead of making a blind guess based on an obscure third-party resource found elsewhere on the Internet, rather consult the official documentation from the vendor itself.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie was not getting deleted because I was using a response.sendRedirect before the response.addCookies.