# Is there spring boot jwt logout solution in using Cookie storage?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

```
I stored jwt token in  Cookie Storage .
```

I want to remove or expire this token in logout action . how should I do ? Can somebody give me advice?Thank you. I use this following code :

```
final String token=jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetials);
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token",token);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);`enter code here`
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [Delete cookie from a servlet response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821919/delete-cookie-from-a-servlet-response)

Create a new cookie with a value of null and add it to the response. So you would replace

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token",token);
```

with

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token",null);
```