# deleting a cookie using java

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

i have written the next code:

```
public void delete(MyType instance) {
        List<MyType> myList = this.getAll();

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        List<Cookie> cookieList = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
        cookieList = Arrays.asList(cookies);
        for(Cookie cookie:cookieList) {
            if(Long.valueOf(cookie.getValue()) == instance.getId()) {
                cookieList.remove(cookie);
            }
        }
        myList.remove(instance);
        cookies = (Cookie[]) cookieList.toArray();
}
```

the issue is next: when i delete the cookie from the cookielist, how i can put the updated cookielist (without deleted cookie) back to the client? request or response don't have any `*.setCookies();` methods.
or cookies will update automatically?
best regards.

Comment: Have you try to put it in your HTTP HEADERS?

Comment: @jocelyn nope, i didn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the very same cookie with a `null` value and a max age of `0` (and the same path, if you have set a custom one) back on the response by [`HttpServletResponse#addCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29).

```
cookie.setValue(null);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setPath(theSamePathAsYouUsedBeforeIfAny);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you do not need massage the array to a list and back at all. The enhanced for loop works on arrays as good. Also, using `==` to compare `Long` values would only work for values between -128 and 127. You need `equals()` instead. So all in all, the method could look like this:

```
public void delete(MyType instance) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (Long.valueOf(cookie.getValue()).equals(instance.getId())) {
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setPath(theSamePathAsYouUsedBeforeIfAny);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, it's scary to see `request` and `response` being instance variables of some class. Are you sure that the particular class is threadsafe? To understand servlets and threadsafety, you may find this answer helpful: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909).

Comment: @ BalusC so i don't need to call request.getCookies() method and do it via WebUtils.getCookie method?

Comment: I have no idea what `WebUtils.getCookie` method is. Perhaps it's from a 3rd party framework I am not familiar with but which you didn't tell anything about in your question. I just assumed the standard Java EE stack as your question didn't give any indication of a 3rd party framework.

Comment: @ BalusC, i didn't knew that feature about Long values. i'll fix it. thnx.

Comment: Non-primitive, non-`Class<?>` and non-`enum` objects should **always** be compared with `equals()`. The `==` only compares object references. The `Long` (and `Integer`, `Byte`, `Short`, etc) classes cache references with a value between -128 and 127 for better `valueOf()` performance (see also the javadoc and read up the "flyweight pattern").

Comment: i think that's what i wanted and it's the only answer for the moment, so i'll mark it as correct. thnx a lot! :)

Comment: @BalusC @JohnSmith If instead of using [`Long.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), you used [`Long.parsLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-), which returns a primitive, then you could safely do the comparison with `==`.

Comment: given that the domain is also part of the cookie's identity (http://stackoverflow.com/a/891037/274677), shouldn't `Cookie#setDomain` also be used to ensure it overwrites previously set cookies?