# I want to log out my application after browser close in every browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I am calling this code by this `window.onbeforeunload=HandleOnClose;`

This is working fine in IE but not in other browsers. This code is specific for IE but this is not working in other browsers. How can we detect close event of browser in all the browser ?

```
function ConfirmClose()
    {
        if (isIE7Min) //To check for IE Version 7.0 and above
        {   
          var n = window.event.screenX - window.screenLeft; 
          var b = n > document.documentElement.scrollWidth-20;
            if ((b && window.event.clientY < 0) || window.event.altKey) 
            {
                if (!self.closed)
                {
                    refresh = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else   //IE Version 6.0 and below
        {
            if (event.clientY < 0 && event.clientX < 0)
            {
                if (!self.closed)
                {
                    refresh = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*Function for onunload*/

    function HandleOnClose()
    {

        ConfirmClose();

        if (isIE7Min)
        {

            if ((window.event.clientX > 0 && window.event.clientY < 0) || window.event.altKey) 
            {
                if (refresh == true) 
                {           
                    window.open("/DealPricingJavaUAT/DealPricingJsp/Home/logout.jsf");
                    //Code That redirects to the Session Invalidation Page
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (event.clientY < 0 && event.clientX < 0 || window.event.altKey)
            {
                if (refresh == false) 
                {                      
               window.open("/DealPricingJavaUAT/DealPricingJsp/Home/logout.jsf");
                // Code That redirects to the Session Invalidation Page    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even though the answer from gigadot is right, trying to catch non error closes can be done in some browsers. Take a look at onbeforeunload, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to always log user out. If there is a crash on user's web browser, the client-side code will never get executed. Some web browsers shutdown itself very fast and don't wait to execute the client-side code.

You should find an alternative solution, like logging out on server side if user is not active for certain period of time.

Comment: i have session time out on server for 30 min .
but my server performance low down when user create session again and again ,,

Comment: don't rely on server time out. create your own time out system.

Comment: Session timeout is just configureable in server side.

Comment: ok but suppose some one open browser 15 time without log out then it will create the 15 session for that, and again server performance will be low down ..
thats why i want to call logout page after browser close ..

Comment: if the same web browser is opened 15, it doesn't mean there will be 15 sessions. There can be many more or fewer depending on how you design your system.

Comment: set cookies maxage is probably your best alternative if you don't want to write you own timeout system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to detect when the user closes the browser.
If you are using java and using cookies to check if the user is logged-in, you can
do cookie.setMaxAge(-1).

This will make sure that cookies are deleted when browser closes.