# How to remove a session ID in a redirect Apache2 AJP load balancing Tomcats

Tags: java, servlets, apache2, load-balancing, ajp

Ok, first we have a java servlet application that runs on Tomcat nodes. In front of this we have Apache2 using the ajp connector doing load-balancing.

Generally, we do rolling updates for bugfixes. This entails using the Apache Jk Status Manager to disable a node and redirect all new traffic to an active node. This allows the users to remain on the old node until they log off. After a long wait, I can generally stop the disabled node and move the update in. Then activate that node and disable the other ones.

The problem I want to solve is preventing inactive users from reconnecting to the disabled node after their session has ended. There is reference to this problem in the documentation.

> A final note about setting activation to disabled: The session id coming with a request is send either as part of the request URL (;jsessionid=...) or via a cookie. When using bookmarks or browsers that are running since a long time, it is possible to send a request carrying an old and invalid session id pointing at a disabled member. Since the load balancer does not have a list of valid sessions, it will forward the request to the disabled member. Thus draining takes longer than expected. To handle such cases, you can add a Servlet filter to your web application, which checks the request attribute JK_LB_ACTIVATION. This attribute contains one of the strings "ACT", "DIS" or "STP". **If you detect "DIS" and the session for the request is no longer active, delete the session cookie and redirect using a self-referential URL.** The redirected request will then no longer carry session information and thus the load balancer will not send it to the disabled worker. The request attribute JK_LB_ACTIVATION has been added in version 1.2.32.

The question I have is in reference to the **bolded statement**. How do I prevent the sending of the JSESSION ID in the redirect.

The code I'm using right now just ends up in an infinite redirect loop.

```
       public final void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                    throws IOException, ServletException
            {
        ...
            String status = (String)req.getAttribute("JK_LB_ACTIVATION");
                         log.info("Node status " + status);
                         if("DIS".equals(status)) {
                            log.info("Status disabled, looking for session ");
                            Collection<HttpSession> col = TurbineSession.getActiveSessions();
                            Iterator<HttpSession> it = col.iterator();
                            boolean found = false;
                            String requestSession = req.getRequestedSessionId();
                            sessionSearch: while(it.hasNext()) {
                                HttpSession session = (HttpSession) it.next();
                                log.info("Comparing " + requestSession + " to " + session.getId());
                                if(session.getId().equals(requestSession)) {
                                    found = true;
                                    break sessionSearch;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!found) {
                                String path = "mypath";
                    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
                    for(Cookie tempCookie : cookies) {
                        if(requestSession.equals(tempCookie.getValue())) {
//                          tempCookie.setValue(null);
                            tempCookie.setMaxAge(0);
//                          tempCookie.setPath(path);
                            res.addCookie(tempCookie);
                        }
                    }
                    res.sendRedirect(path);
                    return;
                            }
                         }
    ...
    }
```

Inspecting the redirects with Firebug shows the JSESSIONID still be included in the redirect. How do I remove it? Everything I can see referring to removing cookies doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tried Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID",requestSession);
               cookie.setMaxAge(0);
               res.addCookie(cookie);  doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)

Adding

```
tempCookie.setPath("/");
```

rather than using the complete path or leaving it out  finally did (appears to do) the trick. I'm sure there's some esoteric explanation.

Answer (score -1):

It's as described in the quote. There is either a ;jsessionid= in the URL or a Cookie: header in the request.

I don't know why you're doing the session search. You only need to test session.isValid().

Comment: An answer that's the equivalent of RTFM, without providing any solution or direction at the solution is beyond useless.