# Use Liferay to authenticate users from separate standalone application

Tags: authentication, liferay

I'm trying to get my standalone webapplication to use my Liferay 6.2 as "user store". That means I want the user to log in to Liferay and then be able to move on to another application with some credentials and user specific information passed as well. Moving on and passing information is already working, the issue I'm having right now is making sure the user-object that is passed on is the user that is actually logged in right now.

I use the LFR_SESSION_STATE_ cookie do determine the logged in user. But when I log in again with another user I get a second cookie with a different user-id. So now I need to make sure that I'm passing the correct user. The USER_UUID cookie does not contain the same uuid as provided by Liferay (as of now I didn't check if it's a hash of the uuid).

Long story short, I'm looking for a way to recognize the currently logged in user and be able to pass the credentials and additional information to my application.

I will take care of security concerns like manipulated cookies etc. subsequently. Maybe that will raise another question wenn I get to that point ;-)

I'd really appriciate any help or push in the right direction.
Thanks in advance guys ... sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Make your application a portlet application
- Publish your Liferay Database [through LDAP](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15186785) (EE only) and use a separate SSO application
- Create a Liferay-Hook that sets a cookie (to "/") containing the required user information - encryption and signatures are on yourself. You can create [hooks](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-acti-4) that get executed on every successful login

Comment: Thanks for your help. Developing a Hook was an obvious but nontheless brilliant idea. Didn't cross my mind and basically solved my problem. Just one more question if I may: Do you know if I can delete cookies from another path? Since my hook is running in liferay my path is "/". Know I want to terminate a session of another application with another path "/someapp" on logout. Do you know if and how I can do this? I tried to set MaxAge = 0 to this specific cookie but it wasn't deleted. My fault or some kind of protection to avoid random deletions of cookies belonging to other applications? Tanks

Comment: maxAge=0 should do the trick, checked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935 - you might want to monitor the http traffic (e.g. with firebug network monitor) to see if the appserver keeps you from manipulating cookies on a path that is supposed to be under control of a different webapp. Worst thing, you might need some stupid http-redirect to that application and delete it from there. Not pretty, but if it's the way that solves the problem...... (try monitoring the http headers first)