# How to write servlet filter to destroy all cookies related to domain on browser

Tags: jsf, cookies, servlet-filters, wildfly

I am new to servlet filter.

I am using JSF 2.2, Wildfly 8.1. I have figured out that if user clicks log out link when session is already expired then when user logs in again the system will continiously fire exception of session expired. BalusC wrote to write servlet filter which will delete all cookies of specific domain before user will see welcome page.

How to write servlet filter which will destroy all cookies related to specific domain (domain.com) when new session will start? I played with it and absolutely confused. sorry for my a little experience in jsf.

Comment: Your question would be even better when you post the code you're working with here

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `cookie.setMaxAge(0);`for all the cookie for that domain.

Inside your filter(which should be used for `Logout` request only) or in Logout servlet(if any) you can write below line to delete all cookie.

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
       cookie.setValue("");
       cookie.setPath("/");
       cookie.setMaxAge(0);
       resp.addCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```