# Struts2 Remove Cookies when user logs out

Tags: cookies, struts2

I am trying to make my application to remove the cookies that are set, so whenever the user clicks logout, the cookies are removed. I set my cookies like this, with the CookieProvider.

```
public Set<Cookie> getCookies(){

      Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();

      Cookie name = new Cookie("name", userInfo.getName() );
      name.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); 
      name.setPath("/"); 
      cookies.add(name);
}
```

I do remove the user from the sessionMap whenever the user clicks on logout. Like this:

```
  public String execute() throws Exception{

             sessionMap.remove("userId");               
             return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Is there a simple way of also removing the cookies in Struts2 whenever the user logs out?

Comment: Nonsense. Why do you use cookies in the first place?

Comment: What's nonsense? It's required for a school project.

Comment: @JohnPulple, your whole series of cookie-related questions seems to me as a classic case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214186). Try describing WHAT you want to achieve and WHY you want to achieve it, leaving the HOW to the answers, not as part of the question, because itself might be wrong in the first place

Comment: Ah school project... what a strange project BTW :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/890935/1700321)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am trying to explain what I want to achieve, in this case, to remove cookies when the user logs out, cookies that I have set earlier. I'm obviously very new to web development, and working with struts2/cookies, so I apologize if the questions are bad formatted.

Comment: No, my comment was about the XY problem. Please read the answer in that question... btw sometimes it happens that you have a problem X, you figure out a solution Y, but when you got in trouble you start asking about how to fix the solution Y, that might be wrong... if you asked about the problem X, someone could have suggested you the solution Z, that it's the right one. This might applies to any kind of question. BTW this doesn't seem to be your case because if it's a school project, they've probably asked you exactly this, even if it is a nonsense.

Comment: @JohnPulple: Maybe you can share with us exact goal of the project.

Comment: @AleksandrM The exact goal is to build a website with struts 2, and under the requirements, it says that the website should handle cookies, and when the session is closed, the cookies should be removed. Maybe that wasn't what I described?

Comment: Ok. Look at the answer in linked question.

Comment: @AleksandrM I've looked at the answers in the linked question, and I am trying to make it work for Struts2, since the answers are for Servlets. Thanks for trying to help at least.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but I think perhaps you can set the cookie again but this time to `null` when they log out.  Then you could check for a null cookie to see if they are logged in or not.