# How to remove all set cookies using a loop in JSP..?

Tags: jsp, cookies, removeall

I'm new to Java Server Pages, so I want to know;

How to remove all set cookies using a loop in JSP..?

Or is there any method to remove all cookies..?, like following method to remove all sessions.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

Comment: Please don't down rate this question.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<%
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
         cookie.setMaxAge(0);
         response.addCookie(cookie);
     }
%>
<HTML>
```

From the Javadoc for `Cookie.setMaxAge()`:

> A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

Make sure you delete the Cookies before the response object has been constructed.  And it would be better for you to handle such business logic on the server side and to avoid JSP's entirely.