# cannot delete cookies from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I need help on deleting Cookies from servlet.

I need to implement simple chat program:

in the doPost() function I check if the input is valid (no empty messages/username and that the user name only consist of numbers or letters).
If there is a problem with the input I create new Cookie for the error message
and add it to the response (**I do not set the path or the domain of the cookie**).

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //--- Get Data From User ---
    String userName= request.getParameter("userName");
    String msg= request.getParameter("comment");

    //--- Check if 'userName or 'msg' are empty ---
    userName = userName.trim();
    msg = msg.trim();

     //--- Response ---
    if (userName.isEmpty() || msg.isEmpty() || !userName.matches(pattern))
    {
       if (userName.isEmpty() || msg.isEmpty())
        {
            //store new Cookie for the error message 
            Cookie c1 = new Cookie("erorrEmpty", "\"<p>ERROR: \\\"username\\\" and \\\"message\\\" should not be empty.</p>\"");
           // c1.setMaxAge(60*60);
            //c1.setPath(".");
            response.addCookie(c1);
        }
       if (!userName.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
        {
            //store new Cookie for the error message 
            Cookie c2 = new Cookie("errorNotAlphanumeric", "\"<p>ERROR: \\\"username\\\" should consist of letters and numbers only.</p>\"");
                           // c2.setMaxAge(60*60);
                           // c2.setPath(".");
            response.addCookie(c2);
        }

        //--- display form with errors ---
        response.sendRedirect("/ex3/MsgServlet?action=1");

    }
    else
    {
        // Insert New Message To The Vector....

        //--- display all messages ---
        response.sendRedirect("/ex3/MsgServlet?action=2");
    }
}
```

In the doGet() function I check if there are any errors in the cookies and save them in a string that I will display in the HTML output.
After I save the errors I try to delete the Cookies (by maxAge(0)) but surprisingly it does not work...

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = null;   
    try{      

        //--- Determine Content Type ---
        response.setContentType("text/html"); 

        //--- Get Writer ---
         out = response.getWriter(); 


         if (request.getParameter("action").equals("1"))    //display form with errors if exists
         {

            String error = "";

            //--- names of cookies to look for ---
            String emptyFiledsCookieName = "erorrEmpty";
            String notAlphanumericCookieName = "errorNotAlphanumeric";

            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                for(Cookie cookie: cookies) 
                {
                    if (emptyFiledsCookieName.equals(cookie.getName()) || notAlphanumericCookieName.equals(cookie.getName()) )
                    {
                       error=error+ cookie.getValue() +"\n";
                    }
                }

                for(Cookie cookie: cookies) 
                {
                    if (emptyFiledsCookieName.equals(cookie.getName()) || notAlphanumericCookieName.equals(cookie.getName()) )
                    {
                       cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                    }
                }
            }


               out.println("<html><head><title>");
               out.println("compose message</title>");
               out.println("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
               out.println("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">");
               out.println("</head><body>");

               //--- Print Errors ---
                out.println(error);

               out.println("<form action=\"MsgServlet\" method=\"POST\" id=\"usrform\">");
               out.println("<p>username:</p>");
               out.println("<input type=text name=userName><br>");
               out.println("<input type=submit value=\"post\"></form>");
               out.println("<br><p>message:</p><textarea rows=\"4\" cols=\"50\" name=\"comment\" form=\"usrform\"></textarea>");
               out.println("</body></html>");

          }
         else if (request.getParameter("action").equals("2"))
         {
             //display messages

         }
}
```

I saw other questions in this issue but they mentioned the setDomain() and setPath() functions. This is  not relevant for me because I did not use them in the creation of the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get it, you can change it !

You have to add it to the answer.

```
HttpServletResponse resp

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();    

Cookie the_cookie // get the good one !

the_cookie.setMaxAge(0);

resp.addCookie(the_cookie);
```

or see that: [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

getMaxAge(int) :

- Gets the maximum age in seconds of this Cookie.
- By default, -1 is returned, which indicates that the cookie will persist until browser shutdown.
- if negative, means the cookie persists until browser shutdown.

  ```
  public static Cookie eraseCookie(String CookieName, String  Path) {
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie(CookieName, "");
  cookie.setMaxAge(0);// Set as a o 
  cookie.setPath(Path);
  return cookie;
  }
  ```

  Happy to Help