# Cookie cleanup not working with java code, I am trying to remove a cookie from parent domain

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

I am stuck in cookie clean up issue.
We have created cookie value with domain : .www.parent.com 
And later we changed code base to create cookie values in domain : .parent.com
This is giving us cookie values from both the domains and messing up with our code. Is there a way to delete cookies from .www.parent.com via java code ?

I have already tries doing like this :

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("oldCookie" , null);
 cookie.setMaxAge(0); or cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
 cookie.setPath("/");
 response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)

Comment: @emanuele This is not same issue. My domain name for set cookie is not same. I want to delete the cookie present with domain name set to ".www.parent.com", when my current domain is set to '.parent.com'. And i have tried the solutions provided in that tread as well, as i have mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get all the cookies the client has stored and check them, using `request.getCookies()`, which returns a Cookie array.

In that way, you'll need to check anyone for the wanted domain and set its TTL with something like this:

```
Cookie[] c=request.getCookies();
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
    if(c[i].getDomain().equals(".www.parent.com")){
        c[i].setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(c[i]);
    }
}
```

This way, the cookie you're passing to the `response` should have exactly the same name, path and any other attribute except for `maxAge` value being 0.

Comment: You cant not access the domain of a cookie request . So c[i].getDomain().equals(".www.parent.com") will always give us null. And even though i can identify the incorrect cookie with its value. Its maxAge = 0 is not reflecting.